# Defining Durandal ViewModel with TypeScript

Tags: javascript, requirejs, typescript, durandal, single-page-application

How can I do this?

Some of the examples I have seen, look **horrible** for example, the following, which does not read like an OO code at all, and hence what's the point of TypeScript if it's gonna be a hack. I can't exactly get intellisense on the following at all, since there's no class definition. So I have a compiled code, with no intellisense, without being able to enforce encapsulation etc - so why bother wasting time?

```
/// <reference path="../durandal/durandal.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="../../scripts/knockout.d.ts" />

import app = require("durandal/app");
import http = require("durandal/http");

export function activate() {
   .
   .
   .
}
```

Other examples are even more funky, by exporting a variable declaration.

The resulting code is not much better, it's DI-ing this variable called `exports` And the code just keeps adding properties to it, which does not make sense.

If I were to write this all in javascript, I return a new object may be in JSON notation - that I can understand, a proper factory method/class. A lot less work, cleaner and no time wasted compiling.

So can someone explain what's going on?

1. Why is the code creating properties on a DI-ed `exports` object? It's like a mutant pass by reference.
2. Is there a more OO way of doing this? I can see myself exporting a class, but this is just too weird and goes against everything I believe to be right and just. Ok that was an exaggeration, but sure feels that way.

Answer (score 1):

> The resulting code is not much better, it's DI-ing this variable called exports And the code just keeps adding properties to it, which does not make sense.

This is the way web (amd) works. Its dependent on requirejs : http://requirejs.org/ and even jquery (pick any file from https://github.com/jquery/jquery/tree/master/src) uses a similar pattern e.g. : https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/deferred.js#L1-L5

> If I were to write this all in javascript, I return a new object may be in JSON notation - that I can understand, a proper factory method/class. A lot less work, cleaner and no time wasted compiling.

You can do this with TypeScript as well by *not* using external modules and compiling with `--out` flag.

> Why is the code creating properties on a DI-ed exports object? It's like a mutant pass by reference.
>   Is there a more OO way of doing this? I can see myself exporting a class, but this is just too weird and goes against everything I believe to be right and just. Ok that was an exaggeration, but sure feels that way.

You need to learn about External / Internal modules. In a nutshell external modules depend upon a module system (amd for the browser, provided by e.g. requirejs, commonjs for the server e.g nodejs). If you've never heard of amd/commonjs you probably shouldn't care. EXCEPT the library you are trying to use (durandal) needs you to use it. This means your javascript code would not be as simple as you think it would be.

PS: I have a video explaining typescript module systems : http://www.youtube.com/watch?hd=1&v=KDrWLMUY0R0